# Questions regarding custom model methods in DataMapper

Tags: php, codeigniter, datamapper

I recently decided to implement DataMapper in my CI application, it works great so far. I have though a couple of questions regarding the use of custom model methods. Let's say I want to update a users cookies when he logs into my application. My controller looks something like this (I've exlcuded the class definition):

```
        if(isset($_POST['login_rememberme']) && $_POST['login_rememberme'] == TRUE)
        {
            // There's already a user object defined here called $user

            // Create two new random cookies
            $pid = rand_str(40);
            $sid = rand_str(40);

            // Set the cookies in the users browser
            setcookie('pid', $pid, COOKIE_EXPIRE, '/', FALSE, '', TRUE);
            setcookie('sid', $sid, COOKIE_EXPIRE, '/', FALSE, '', TRUE);

            // Update users relationsship with the new cookies in the db
            ???
        }
```

The cookies are stored in a seperate table from the user-data (password, email etc.). The relationship between the cookies and users are defined in a table called cookies_users. I'm thinking that I could create a method in my 'cookie' model called setCookies, and allow two parameters, **sid** and **pid**, but then how do I use the already established user model in that method, do I pass it to the method? Reading the DataMapper I'm not fairly convinced if it's recommended to throw all the logic in the controller and keep the models clean as possible, or if it's okay to pack your models with custom methods. Anybody know what is up and down in this one?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about Codeigniter is that it's flexible about what goes in your models or controllers (technically, you could forego models altogether, but that kind of defeats the purpose of MVC). There are different schools of thought on the "fat model, thin controller vs fat controller, thin model" debate, but my personal preference is to have all direct database access in the models, essentially extending DataMapper. What I've found, though, is that you don't generally need to add a lot of custom functions if you harness the functions available to you through DataMapper (I end up with about half a dozen, generally, and most of them are just complex Selects, validation, or calls to JSON encoding for APIs, which might be reused in other controllers).

If you call the model functions through the object, you should be able to use `$this` to access the established object. From there, you can perform your custom stuff as necessary.

So, for example, you might have `$cookie->setCookie($sid, $pid)` in your controller, and in your model you might have (code not tested, just an example):

```
function setCookie($sid, $pid){
  $this->pid = $pid;
  $this->sid = $sid;
  // Do other custom stuff.
  return $this->save();
}
```

What you have in your models depends largely on what you're trying to accomplish, and whether what you're trying to accomplish can be done natively through DataMapper. For basic CRUD and relationships, I generally end up with just objects in the controller.

As an aside, there are a number of Authentication libraries that handle session. You might want to consider checking them out if you're trying to build an authentication system.